# Can I control fan speeds on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, arch-linux, fan

I'm using Arch Linux on a **HP Pavillion 15-bc001nq** and I installed **nbfc** (NoteBook Fan Control) as shown here (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control) but I can't find a good configuration for my laptop. Can I install other package to control my fan speeds or what should I do?

Comment: Are your pins connected to 3-pins or 4-pins?  The answer to that question, will determine if your fans can be controlled by software, or if they will always run at the same speed.

Comment: @Ramhound I have two fans and both of them are connected via 4-pins. So what does that mean?